# Can we destroy activity without call stop() method?

Tags: android

```
In activity life cycle to execute as like.
onCreate()
onDestroy()
```

**it means without call stop() method in activity life cycle.**
how it is possible ?

Comment: use `finish` method to destroy activity.

Answer (score 2):

Use `finish();` to destroy activity.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to call `stop(`) method. Android system automatically go thru those life cycle methods.

But apparently `onDestroy()` always called after `onStop()`.

If you want to kill activity just call `finish()`, it will destroy your activity.

But remember again `onStop()` always called as system level, follows the activity life cycle if you call `finish()`.

**Note:** If system kills your application or activity to utilize memory there is no guarantee to call these methods from activity life cycle.

Comment: I believe the OP is wondering why they observe `onCreate()` and `onDestroy()` being called, without `onStop()` called in between.

Answer (score 1):

```
    public class ExampleActivity extends Activity {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.empty);
            System.out.println("in onCreate");
            finish();
     }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();
        System.out.println("in onDestroy");
    }
    }
```

> when the activity run then call onCreate() method and onDestroy()
>   method